# How to create sorted key/parent in string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have key/parent structured like this :

```
[Object { parent="0", key="5961"}, Object { parent="5961", key="5960"}, Object { parent="5960", key="5826"}, Object { parent="5826", key="5841"}, Object { parent="5841", key="5915"}]
```

Root object is parent="0" all other are children and that is solved like this :

```
$.each (data, function(index,value){    

    key += "/" +  value.key;    

});
```

The problem starts when I have more root objects and need to have first root then all children...second root then all children and so on...This is problematic object :

```
[Object { parent="0", key="5961"}, Object { parent="0", key="5962"}, Object { parent="5961", key="5960"}, Object { parent="5824", key="2237"}, Object { parent="5962", key="5824"}, Object { parent="5960", key="5826"}, Object { parent="2237", key="5834"}, Object { parent="2237", key="5838"}, Object { parent="5826", key="5841"}, Object { parent="2237", key="5843"}, Object { parent="5865", key="5846"}, Object { parent="5865", key="5862"}, Object { parent="5838", key="5865"}, Object { parent="5843", key="5874"}, Object { parent="5834", key="5894"}, Object { parent="5865", key="5912"}, Object { parent="5841", key="5915"}, Object { parent="5865", key="5935"}]
```

As you can see two root parent="0". There can be more than two root nodes.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this your actual JavaScript code, or just some console output?

Comment: Why not resolve this by considering them as having a single root again; Have a `{'parent': '-1', 'key': '0'}` and then trim off the initial `/` produced by your current code?

Comment: That is the problem..they are not sorted by root node, as you can see two root nodes (parent = 0) are first, children are also unsorted. Parent/Key pair is only way to determine relations. So my question is how to sort parent/key pairs in correct relation.